# copy file to folder in known location but random name

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

I need to move one configuration file to somewhere else,
The thing is that I don't know the name of the parent folder that I want to move it **to** because the name is being created randomly.

```
 sourcefolder                           destinationfolder
          |                              |    |StaticFolder
          |                              |        | AnotherStaticFolder 
          |                              |           | Randomfolder
          |                                              | StaticFolder
          \cofiguration.conf                                  \cofiguration.conf
```

How can I do it this with xcopy or any batch command?

Comment: in your schematic representation it seems like it is the destination folder that has a random name but in the description you're saying it is the sourcefolder that has a random name ( "...folder that I want to move it **from**..." ). Which of the 2 will have the random name??

Comment: Sorry, you were right. Edited

Comment: How will you recognize the destination folder then?? Or do you have to create a new one each time you copy??

Comment: The destination folder is being created after I install my app (created with random name), After its being created I want to copy to it

Comment: Which app??  and is there a way to ask the app for the name of the folder??

Comment: NO, I only know it start with temp*

Comment: You'll have to search for a way to get the folder name first ... you can't copy files without specifiying their destination. You can try to search a way to dynamically ask your app for the foldername, you can search it manually and hold it in a variable, ... but you'll have to get the folder name first.

Comment: There must be a way to use REGEX to do it...

Comment: Maybe ... maybe not ... but as you don't provide information about the application I can't help you with that one. I can still provide you some commands that could help you find a folder using wildcards though: [`FORFILES`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) or [`FOR /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just doing:

```bat
@for /d %%a in ("C:\destinationfolder\StaticFolder\AnotherStaticFolder\temp*") do @copy "C:\sourcefolder\configuration.conf" "%%a"
```

This assumes there will be only one folder beginning with temp in the random folder name location.

**[Edit /]**

With the change that you've now added you should still be able to utilise the same base code and just add an extra if layer:

```bat
@for /d %%a in ("C:\destinationfolder\StaticFolder\AnotherStaticFolder\temp*"
) do @if exist "%%a\StaticFolder\" (
        @copy "C:\sourcefolder\configuration.conf" "%%a\StaticFolder")
```

Comment: works :) , but now I realize that I need the file to be copied into a subfolder of the random folder that is being created, I changed the schema so it will be clearer.  I tried this: for /d %%a in ("C:\destinationfolder\StaticFolder\AnotherStaticFolder\temp*\staticFolder") do copy "C:\sourcefolder\configuration.conf" "%%a"    but it doesn't work

Comment: I have appended an Edit to my response to suit your changed parameters.